# error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant

Tags: visual-c++

I keep getting this error on my project and i cant figure it out! please help!

error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'

the line is:

```
while (selection == ('a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i','A','B' 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I');
```

also i know there is an easier way to write that line out but im not sure how i can do it. im a beginner at this so can any of you pros edit this line for me!

Comment: could you expand on the code a bit for your second request of writing this better - what is a selection?  Also format the code in a code block.

Comment: All the answers so far are assuming 'char selection'  what is the rest of the code block?

Answer (score 6):

How many open parentheses do you have?

How many closed parentheses do you have?

Are these the same number? If not, where is one missing?

Also, the syntax `a == (b,c,d)` is not shorthand for `a == b || a == c || a == d` like you seem to think. It's actually equivalent to `a == d` due to the way the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) works.

To be completely explicit, what you actually want is this:

```
while (selection == 'a' || selection == 'b' ||
       selection == 'c' || selection == 'd' ||
       selection == 'e' || selection == 'f' ||
       selection == 'g' || selection == 'h' ||
       selection == 'i' || selection == 'A' ||
       selection == 'B' || selection == 'C' ||
       selection == 'D' || selection == 'E' ||
       selection == 'F' || selection == 'G' ||
       selection == 'H' || selection == 'I')
{
   /* Do stuff */
}
```

Or, to be a lot more consice about it, you can take advantage of the fact that the letters are arranged alphabetically in the ASCII table, and write

```
while (tolower(selection) >= 'a' && tolower(selection) <= 'i')
{
   /* Do stuff */
}
```

This requires inclusion of `<ctype.h>` for the `tolower` function.

Comment: In addition to that, the OP really don't want to compare 'selection' to the result of the comma operator.

Comment: well when i add a closed parentheses it gives me this along with the the original error:

\error C2059: syntax error : ')'

this is what the line looks like when i add the closed parentheses:

 while (selection == ('a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i','A','B' 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'));

Comment: further hint - while loop definition doesn't normally end with a ; unless you don't want it to do anything

Comment: so how should i write the line out without having to use all the commas. i need to include the letter A through I (lowercase and uppercase)

Comment: when i take ; out it says that im missing the semicolon.   now im confused.

Comment: I suggest you find a good introductory book on C. You seem to be confused about the basic syntax of a `while` loop, which is somewhat below the level at which you can get useful help from the Internet.

Comment: there is a missing , between 'B' and 'C' thus breaking the CSV list and causing the expectation of a ) before the 'C' - that would fix the syntax but not resolve process issue you have

Answer (score 1):

Given your comments on Tyler's post, it seems like what you really want is:

```
while ((selection >= 'a' && selection <= 'i') || (selection >= 'A' && selection <= 'I'))
{
    // loop
}
```

Characters can be compared as if they were numbers (because they *are* numbers in the CPU), which means that you can check for a range of characters using the `< > <= >=` operators.

Comment: Just note that while this works on PCs, it can break on (for example) IBM mainframes. They use EBCDIC instead of ASCII, and EBCDIC has some non-alphabetic characters between some of the letters -- something like half a doze between 'i' and 'j', and the same number between 'r' and 's'. Likewise with the upper-case letters. [Warning: my memory of the exact letters could be a bit off].

Comment: or make it e.g. :  `while(strchr("abcdefghiABCDEFGHI",selection) != NULL) { ... } `